# How Escalante is compared to Jetty in runtime memory usage?

Tags: scala, jetty, lift, escalante

I'm looking for container for my Lift web application, deployed on OpenShift and I found Escalante.
On [Escalante](http://escalante.io/) site it's [said](http://escalante.io/faq/#why_deploy_lift_applications_on_escalante), that Escalante "optimises the size of the deployment and the memory consumption at runtime". How it's compared to Jetty in memory usage ?

Comment: I would try posting this to the lift list, https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/liftweb. The project lead for Escalante is on it, and you will probably get some more people who have used both.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is the Escalante lead. We still have not compared with other containers such as Jetty. That statement was based on comparisons I did with the base JBoss Application Server container, deploying a standard Lift war versus deploying a Lift war the Escalante way, with a minimal war. The latter was more memory efficient. We will do comparisons with Jetty as we near functionality completion, but we're not at that stage yet.